# QML dynamic columns width

Tags: qt, qml

I have `TableView` with 4 columns. When I enlarge width of main window, I needed enlarge first column width too.

Older way (non QML) was:

```
QTableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch );
```

Now I do something like example bellow, but this is not exactly perfect.

1. When I resize some column, this construction stop working. All columns stay in actual state and stop resizing when main window change his size.
2. When I add new columns in future (forgot rewrite this codeine) or add some columns dynamically, this stop working too.

QML file:  :

```
TableView {  

     id: ccPanel  
     model: ccModel
    TableViewColumn {
        id: ccName
        role: "name"
        title: "Name"
        width: ccPanel.width - ccSize.width - ccDate.width
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        id: ccSize
        role: "size"
        title: "Size"
        width: 60
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        id: ccDate
        role: "Date"
        title: "Datum"
        width: 85
    }
}
```

Do you know how to help me?

Comment: If you set `resizable` as `false` those error should be fixed. But I don't know if the user should be able to resize columns or not.

Comment: No, this settings disable change column size by mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate strange resizing, make the last column non-resizable manually and use the `widthChanged` signals of the columns as well as the signal from the TabView. The following code produces a behavior very close to the Qt TableView header.

```
TableView
{
    id: ccPanel
    model: ccModel
    anchors.fill: parent
    onWidthChanged:ccName.width = Math.max(100, ccPanel.width - ccSize.width - ccDate.width)

    TableViewColumn
    {
        id: ccName
        role: "name"
        title: "Name"
        onWidthChanged: ccDate.width = Math.max(60, ccPanel.width - ccSize.width - ccName.width)
    }
    TableViewColumn
    {
        id: ccSize
        role: "size"
        title: "Size"
        width: 60
        onWidthChanged: ccDate.width = Math.max(85, ccPanel.width - ccSize.width - ccName.width)
    }
    TableViewColumn
    {
        resizable: false
        id: ccDate
        role: "Date"
        title: "Datum"
        width: 85
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is one solution I can think of, but it ain't pretty:

Basically, you have to do manual column management, keep track of all current columns in an array, and each time you add, remove or resize a column, you must execute a function that generates the bindings for the column width dynamically:

```
column.height = Qt.binding(function() { return property_evaluating_expressions })
```

Answer (score 0):

If i thing, here we are. In this time it's not perfect, but it's solution. I respond to the event resizing the main window. Not perfect, because not contain actual NAME size. Sometime during enlarging name jups to new value irrationally.

```
    TableView
    {

        id: ccPanel
        property var oldWidth: ccPanel.width
        model: ccModel

        onWidthChanged:
        {
            var newWidth = ccName.width + (ccPanel.oldWidth - ccName.width - ccDate.width - ccSize.width);
            if(newWidth > 19)
            {
                ccName.width = newWidth
            }
            ccPanel.oldWidth = ccPanel.width;
        }

        TableViewColumn
        {
        ...
        ...
        ...
```